# Django + AWS S3 Bucket: Authenticated Access to S3 Bucket

Tags: django, amazon-s3

I have a S3 bucket with a special directory that I'm dumping user uploaded images that I want to restrict to authenticated users.  It shouldn't be restricted to just the user that uploaded the image.  I'm really trying to avoid setting up a db model for this.  Is there anyway to block anonymous members from the user uploaded images?

So, I have two questions:
How do I go about setting up an anonymous-user-blocked S3 bucket?
AND
How should I access this bucket within a is_authenticated conditional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Set the bucket ACL to private. This will stop anyone but you (the bucket owner) from accessing the objects.
2. Check if the user is_authenticated and if they are...
3. Generate a [signed URL](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html#RESTAuthenticationQueryStringAuth) which is basically a pre authenticated request and give it to the user who can then request the object for some period of time.

Comment: Perfect!  I was hoping AWS had something like this.